# Looking for font that has even-sized letter "E" for a logo design

Tags: fonts, inkscape, logo

Creating a logo and  trying toe find a font that has a equal size letter "E" that can find into each other (like lego bricks I assume). I'm trying to avoid using paths and manipulating the letter that way. I'm using Inkscape.

[image: desin]

Answer (score 3):

It is better that you are designing the "E" by your own. Just make 5 equal thick rectangles and reduce the two with the negative space to their third of size.

Look at the example.

[image]

[image]

Of course you can resize it as you want, but that would be the easiest and fastest solution for you, instead of searching for a font.

Comment: One reason for looking for a font is that it's possible to use it as a "house style" which ties it in to the logo. (A disadvantage is that your house style is then fixed.)